# wkhtmltopdf doesn't understand mm

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate PDF from HTML with wkhtmltopdf --page-width 100 --page-height 100.
There are one picture size 100mm and one div with style width="100mm"
In the result PDF div rectangle less then picture and the picture full width sheet. How it can be? 
Does wkhtmltopdf try convert mm to px with default screen dimension and then back to mm?

Comment: The reason is: pdf was generated on linux server, where is no screen, so it got minimum resolution 800x600, and wkhtmltopdf default screen width is 1024. So it needs just to add --width 800 parameter for wkhtmltopdf

Comment: `--width` isn't a valid option as of version 0.12.1; try using the `--disable-smart-shrinking` option instead.